# Application user locked, password with .mdb file

Tags: passwords

Need some help with an application that sadly i cant get access to anymore as the author no longer supports it.

anyway the application has a .mdb file that when opened i get a list of user's and the associated password but the password box is formatted in the following way A8DB6C7E643D04A361D9F9CA55E3D6B1.

Is this just rubbish or can i get the password from it?

Answer (score 0):

From the used characters one can guess that the string is HexEncoded, means two characters describe one byte. This would result in 16 bytes, which is the same length as an MD5 hash produces.

It can be an MD5 hash or it can be something different, but if all passwords are stored with 32 characters, it is very likely a hash and the password cannot be retrieved, only cracked.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply any easy way to crack the hash? and can anyone help show me the process.  The application has various levels of user we can use the software logged in but options are not available sadly for our user level i have the HexEncoded string for the user we use and obviously know the password would knowing that help with cracking the other?